# Mdadm RAID 5 failed, 1 drive bad 1 good 2 working

Tags: mdadm, raid5

Sorry if the title was a little confusing but I wanted to show a little info.

So I went to turn my pc on and ended up with the nice screen of having a failed array. /dev/sdb1 and /dev/sde1 are within the array and working fine. The drive /dev/sdc1 is marked as failed but when I last ran a scan it was good and is fine through windows, so I hope to use it to fix the array.

/dev/sdd1 is the failed drive that I need to replace and rebuild from, but I can't create the raid array at all due to having 2 disks. Is there a possible way to re-add /dev/sdc1 then replace the other drive without losing all my data?

I would like to add more information, but I'm really not sure where I can go from in terms of the OS.

Thank you for the replies,
Jason.

EDIT:
I tired to assemble the raid array but continue to cycle through /dev/sd[b-c-e]1 is busy...
Will I have to unmount the drives or wait until they are inactive? Sorry if that's a silly question. :(

Comment: First of all, do not use `--create` ;). Second, I think you should check http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/98563/41104 http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97205/41104 http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/96674/41104, they have nice ways to recover data without destroying you array.

Comment: I went and assembled the array but returned `/dev/md0 assembled from 2 drives - not enough to start the array`
Then when I added /dev/sdd1 to the list it returned `/dev/sdd1 has no superblock`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a future reference to anyone, I'm not sure what I did but after running `mdadm --assemble --scan -v` everything worked (degraded though, but the data is there). Just before that I ran `mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev[bcde]1` but got a message that /dev/sdd1 has no superblock.

Anyhoo, best of luck if anyone else has the problem.